# How to handle Version Disability in IBM MobileFirst Platform Operations Console

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

> I have developed Android application using IBM MobileFirst studio and
>   deployed to **IBM Application Center** as **Version 1.0**.

In order to make the **Version Disability** - 
I have modified my worklight.properties as specified below by adding

> - wl.remoteDisable.cache.enabled=**true**
> - wl.remoteDisable.cache.refreshIntervalInSeconds=**1**

I have enabled **wl_remoteDisableRealm** in **authenticationconfig.xml**. This realm is used for remote disable/remote notify functionality in hybrid and native applications.
**changed Version Number to 1.1**

1. Uploaded New **version 1.1** to IBM Application Center saved the **External URL** generated for this new version
2. Logged in to `IBM MobileFirst Platform Operations Console`
3. Home > AppName > Applications > AppName > Selected Android I can see 1.0 and 1.1.
4. Locked 1.0 selected Properties - Application Access is made disabled and give the external URL generated for 1.1
5. When saved the changes I'm getting an**ERROR**: **Notification rule for the "XXXX" application version 1.0 in Android was not changed succesfully.**

Suggest if any modifications need to be done for doing this.

Screen shots taken for the Error and Error Log:

- [Pic1: Error in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ynHcr.png)
- [Pic2: Error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YE7ox.png)

Answer (score 0):

"Lock this version" is not related at all to the Remote Disable feature.
This checkbox means that future deployments of .wlapp files for this version will no longer be possible (in a way, this blocks Direct Update...). Old feature that should probably not be there...

As for the "log". What a log about it? Provide the log from the server, where it shows the entire exception and its stack trace.

I think you are confusing several things in one and it makes the question hard the follow.

Comment: RuntimeMBeanCallable.call() exception

Comment: <ul><li>000004b1 com.worklight.core.jmx.ProjectManagementMXBeanImpl           I FWLSE0275I: Starting transaction with ID 29,911 for 'reject'.  [project Sample]</li><li>
 00000125 com.ibm.worklight.admin.actions.BaseTransaction              I Result: Sample: MFPServer///localost: Rollback</li><li>
00000125 SystemErr R 7743853  WorklightManagementPU-oracle  INFO   [LargeThreadPool-thread-136] openjpa.Runtime - Though you are using optimistic transactions, OpenJPA is now beginning a datastore transaction because you have requested a lock on some data.</li></ul>

Comment: No. It's not related. Open a PMR.